# Is it possible to stop implicit conversion?

Tags: java

Just out of curiosity: say i have a method which takes a double value as a parameter if an int is passed to it, it automatically gets converted(or treated as a double. How can in ensure that only numbers of a float format (0.0) are accepted as arguments when the method is called?

Comment: So you want a programmer who writes ``doSomething(5)`` to fair, where he is *supposed* to have written ``doSomething(5.0)``? The former is fully legal in Java. If this was part of a library, I wouldn't use it, and I would complain on all the forums about this broken practice.

Comment: I'm just curious...why would you ever want to exclude the integer case? - I could see it if you were going the other direction and losing information.  For this case, I can't think why it would ever be undesirable.

Comment: If the method takes a Double, since there is no implicit conversion from int to Double, the compiler wont let the developer try to call it with an int.

Answer (score 8):

You can't, basically. Not in a really meaningful way. I mean, you could do something *horrible* like this:

```java
public void method(double x) {
    // This is the method you want to call
}

@Deprecated
public void method(int x) throws PleaseReadTheDocsException {
    throw new PleaseReadTheDocsException("Don't call the method with an int");
}
```

Then if anyone tries to call `method(5)` they'll get an error message along the lines of "You need to catch `PleaseReadTheDocsException` or add a throws clause." But it's really pretty unpleasant, and highly non-idiomatic. Even then, someone can call `method((double) 5)`.

Comment: I think the solution with two methods is actually quite elegant for the problem. The problem is the problem.

Comment: In the answer, the method is overloaded and thus if anyone calls your method with int gets diverted to the overloaded method where the error is handled. I think it is a correct and elegant solution. I thought of the same solution when I read the question and didn't read the answer yet. +1 from me

Comment: @MichaelGantman: It's not that "the error is handled" - it's that the caller gets an error message which hopefully makes it clear that they shouldn't be calling this overload.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sometimes (quite often) handling the error is just getting an appropriate message to the user. This is the case here. In any case, I agree with your solution, except that you think it is "horrible", and I think it is appropriate for the problem presented

Comment: As Jon points out, this is non-idiomatic and should probably be avoided, and I'm having trouble thinking of a case where you would want to do this. That said, if you *do* decide to go this route, perhaps it would be polite to annotate the "bad" method as `@Deprecated` so users get some kind of hint they're doing something wrong before the code blows up at run time. (EDIT: Oh I see that `PleaseReadTheDocsException` would make this is a compile-time error, which is even better.)

Comment: @dnault: Added the `@Deprecated` annotation too. Let's not leave anyone in doubt :)